# Exception occurs while performing update operation using the java code in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the **jobs.query** API to update the bigquery table records using java. 
While running this as a part of stability tests for a longer time, we get an exception. Excpetion occurs almost after 5 hours, 11 hours...
The problem is, exception returns blank error message, blank cause, and blank stack trace. So, in this case, I am not able to find the actual cause of the error. 
Request your response on this.
Thanks in advance!

```
package app;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.ParseException;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.BigqueryScopes;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.QueryRequest;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.QueryResponse;

public class WhereCLause {

    //Create Entry Point: Main function
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        String projectId = "projectId";

        // Create a new Bigquery client authorized via Application Credentials.
        Bigquery bigquery = createAuthorizedClient();
        String query = "UPDATE datasetId.tableName SET Name = 'RefUpdate' WHERE ID = 001";

        System.out.println(query);
        executeQuery(query, bigquery, projectId);
    }

    public static Bigquery createAuthorizedClient() throws IOException {

        String jsonFilePath="file.json";

        // Create the credential
        HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        InputStream credentialStream = new FileInputStream(new File(jsonFilePath));
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(credentialStream, transport, jsonFactory);
        if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
            credential = credential.createScoped(BigqueryScopes.all());
        }

        return new Bigquery.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName("BigqueryApplication").build();
    }

    private static void executeQuery(String querySql, Bigquery bigquery, String projectId) throws IOException {
        QueryResponse query = bigquery.jobs().query(projectId, new QueryRequest().setQuery(querySql).setUseLegacySql(true)).execute();

        System.out.println(query.getNumDmlAffectedRows());
        System.err.println(query.getErrors());

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Can you provide more details e.g. the code, stack trace, etc so we can help you better :)

Comment: @GrahamPolley Added the code snippet, can you please help now.